# Quickest Way Besides FTP to Upload WordPress Files to a Web Server?

Tags: installation, uploads

Assume I have SSH from a shared/managed-VPS hosting, and FTP access, but no fantastico.

Thanks.

Comment: *@Tal Galili*: What kind of files are you trying to upload; i.e. WordPress inself+plugins, images, or something else? Is this one-time thing or do you need to do it repeatedly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.
There is a script called [easywp.php](http://www.funscripts.net/php-scripts/)
You upload it to your server and run it.
it will install wordpress for you (i.e. download the .gz file, open it, etc ...)

Another option is to download wordpress to your server using wget and ssh.
you can do that using the command:

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
```

if you want that wordpress install in Hebrew:

1. use [this script](http://www.tazone.net/google/wpheb-1file-installation-php-script/) and then upgrade
2. edit the easywp.php so it will download the latest Hebrew version (the name changes with each new release)
3. change the script mentioned in option (1) to get the latest version for you

Comment: Thanks Hannit, it's exactly what I was looking for (I remembered there was something like this a while back, but couldn't find an updated version).  Great help!

Answer (score 3):

Using the wget command is a very quick way of uploading WordPress files to your server but an even "quicker" way would be to install using subversion.

The main benefit to using subversion is that it is easier to update to new versions using the ssh svn commands.

**To install WordPress using svn:**

Create the directory you would like WordPress to reside in or cd to your public_html or root web directory to install in root.

```
$ mkdir my_wp_install_dir

$ cd my_wp_install_dir
```

If you want to install the latest bleeding edge version:

```
$ svn co http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/ .
```

If you want to install the latest stable version add the current version number following tags/ and always add a space then the period after the version number to make sure WordPress gets installed in the directory you are currently in.

```
$ svn co http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/3.0.1 .
```

You would then need to edit the wp-config-sample.php file as usual and save it as wp-config.php

```
$ nano wp-config-sample.php
```

ctrl-x to save then change the name to wp-config.php at the next prompt

Run /wp-admin/install.php as you normally would. and your done.

To update an svn installion to the latest version cd to your installation directory and run:

```
$ svn up //this will update to latest trunk bleeding edge version
```

or if a version 3.0.2 came out and you are not running trunk run

```
$ svn sw http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/3.0.2/ .
```

then run the normal wp-admin/upgrade.php

Comment: SVN is the best way to go. It makes it easier to upgrade and/or downgrade your site. (Should you need to back off of an upgrade for some odd reason.)